# Cannot edit a cell in a data grid view

Tags: .net, winforms, datagridview

On a win form, I have used the editor to bind a data grid view to a MS Access database.  The Data Source created the following objects: Binding Source, Table Adapter, Table Adapter Manager, and a Binding Navigator.  My goal is simply to read the information, allow some editing, and to pass the information to another application; Thus, I do not need to insert/update/delete from the original DB.  Additionally, I added a couple of unbound columns to the view.  So, there are multiple 'bound' columns and a couple of unbound columns.  When I run the application, the data is there.  However, I cannot edit any of the cells ( bound or unbound ).  The grid view read-only property is set to false.  The column read-only property are set to false.  I checked the each field on the table adapter and they are not set to read only.  I'm not sure what else to check.  I appreciate your help in advance.

Additional Details:

In the designer generated code, the columns are being set to readonly.  However, in the actual designer properties I do not see anywhere that relates to these fields.  I'm thinking of manually changing them to false ( I actually did and it does resolve the problem ) and reverted.  Is there an issue with me doing this manually?

```
// 
        // dataGridViewTextBoxColumn2
        // 
        this.dataGridViewTextBoxColumn2.DataPropertyName = "FirstName";
        this.dataGridViewTextBoxColumn2.HeaderText = "FirstName";
        this.dataGridViewTextBoxColumn2.Name = "dataGridViewTextBoxColumn2";
        this.dataGridViewTextBoxColumn2.ReadOnly = true;
        // 
        // dataGridViewTextBoxColumn1
        // 
        this.dataGridViewTextBoxColumn1.DataPropertyName = "LastName";
        this.dataGridViewTextBoxColumn1.HeaderText = "LastName";
        this.dataGridViewTextBoxColumn1.Name = "dataGridViewTextBoxColumn1";
        this.dataGridViewTextBoxColumn1.ReadOnly = true;
        // 
        // dataGridViewTextBoxColumn3
        // 
        this.dataGridViewTextBoxColumn3.DataPropertyName = "Address";
        this.dataGridViewTextBoxColumn3.HeaderText = "Address";
        this.dataGridViewTextBoxColumn3.Name = "dataGridViewTextBoxColumn3";
        this.dataGridViewTextBoxColumn3.ReadOnly = true;
        // 
        // dataGridViewTextBoxColumn4
        // 
        this.dataGridViewTextBoxColumn4.DataPropertyName = "City";
        this.dataGridViewTextBoxColumn4.HeaderText = "City";
        this.dataGridViewTextBoxColumn4.Name = "dataGridViewTextBoxColumn4";
        this.dataGridViewTextBoxColumn4.ReadOnly = true;
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to enable editing in your gridview by setting EditCellOnEnter property to True

Check this out (look for cell editing): http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms993231.aspx

Comment: This link is for the ASP.NET GridView control, it doesn't equate to the WinForm GridView control and it's properties.  I looked at the link, but it didn't help in tracking down my issue.  However, thanks for your help. If you have any other suggestions, I'm all ears.

Comment: I'm so sorry. I didn't notice it was a win forms grid. I corrected my answer.

Answer (score 0):

When i edit my DataGridView's Columns property, i can see: [1] a Read-Only checkbox in the Add Column dialog (between the Visible and Frozen checkboxes near the OK and Cancel buttons), and [2] a Read Only property for each added Column (in the Behavior area, if you're using Categorized View).